# Is there a way to change select-list for new custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, hooks

When you add a category in the admin-panel, the adminstrator can select it's parent. Something like:

```
- Category1
-- Subcategory1 to Category1
-- Subcategory2 to Category1
-- Subcategory3 to Category1
....
- Category2
-- Subcategory1 to Category2
-- Subcategory2 to Category2
-- Subcategory3 to Category2
....
```

I have created a custom taxonomy. 
Is there a way to change these options to be only parent - selection like this for this specific taxonomy?

```
- Category1
- Category2
....
```

?

(Is there a hook for this for a taxonomy at all?)

Comment: It can be done but you're going to have to get a bit tricky. You should be able to get the gist of it from the non-hierarchical version of your answer (http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wordpress-custom-taxonomy-input-panels/). You more or less need to apply the same concept to categories and add the JS handler to populate the second select box.

Comment: @ImperativeIdeas - Thanks for your línk! I thought the basic idea behind that link was very good, but I think it complicated to much for that special case I had. I've answered myself, so someone else hopefully might got helped in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If someone else stumble upon this kind of question, here's my solution to it: (without having to mangage any metaboxes etc)

```
add_action('categorycourses_add_form_fields','categorycourses_edit_form_fields');
add_action('categorycourses_edit_form_fields','categorycourses_edit_form_fields');

//Function only showing parent categories when editing or adding new category-courses
function categorycourses_edit_form_fields() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
       var level = 1;
       //Go down in hierarchy from level1 and remove each level until there are no levels anymore
       //Don't do anything with level-0 because we want to show parent-categories
       while ( level < $("form .form-field #parent").find(".level-" +  level).length>0 ) { 
            $("form .form-field #parent").find(".level-1").remove(); //Remove level
       }
    });
    </script>    
<?php
}
```

(categorycourses is a taxonomy, and if you wish to use the code just change the taxonomy 
like

```
add_action('{taxonomy}_add_form_fields','{taxonomy}_edit_form_fields');
add_action('{taxonomy}_edit_form_fields','{taxonomy}_edit_form_fields');
```

)